# How to read data from Ggraph object in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

How can I read data from the below code? Right now we are redirecting to a particular screen, but before redirecting we need to get some values from this graph object. This is the sample code from the JournalEntry base graph. I tried to get the view names but that didn't work

```
IDocGraphCreator creator = GetGraphCreator(doc.Module, doc.BatchType);

        if (creator != null)
        {
            PXGraph graph = creator.Create(doc);

            if (graph != null) //how to read data from this object
            {
                throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, true, "")
                {
                    Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow
                };
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is this being used for a hyperlink? if so you can just add a selector the field and allowedit on the page and it will work automatically. (just in case that is the goal)

Answer (score 0):

I would use PXGraph.CreateInstance< Newgraph >(); to create the graph, and then you can manipulate before redirecting. Here is an example of viewing a customer from the CCTransactionsHistoryEnq screen.

```
CustomerMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CustomerMaint>();
graph.BAccount.Current = graph.BAccount.Search<Customer.bAccountID>(pmInstance.BAccountID);
if (graph.BAccount.Current != null)
{
    throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, true, Messages.ViewCustomer) { Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow };
}
```

You should be able to read the information as well from the graph, or call other functions on the graph this way as well.

Comment: Hi, the problem is we don't know to which screen it will redirect, for example, I have two records with same IN module, one batch will take me to Inventory Receipts and other will take me to Inventory Transfers. My question is how should i know to which graph it is taking me.

Comment: the answer will be in your GetGraphCreator method.

Comment: Hi Rick, if possible can you please share me the code snippet

Comment: The graph you specify in the CreateInstance is where the redirection will go. If you want it to go to Inventory Transfers, you should create an instance of INTransferEntry, and for InventoryReceipts you should use INReceiptEntry